# How to efficiently extract specific metadata for many shapefiles?

Tags: ogr, command-line, ogrinfo, feature-count

I have a directory with 50 subdirectories containing a total of 300 shapefiles which I would like to query for their feature count and output to a text file.

Thus far I am able to get the feature count for all shapefiles in 1 subdirectory using **ogrinfo**:

```
for %f in (*.shp) do ogrinfo -al -so %f
```

This outputs a lot of additional metadata and tags which need to be stripped out manually.

Introducing the following to this script results in the feature counts all equaling 1:

```
-dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT('ID'))"
```

I'd love to learn a command line solution to efficiently parse the ogrinfo output. I recognize that this could require some **awk/grep** type solutions which I can learn to do, but I am working with a standard Windows 10 install of OSGEO /GDAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findstr` with multiple search terms.

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.shp) do ( 
    echo %f  >> shape_list.txt
    ogrinfo -al -so %f| findstr /I /c:"layer name" /c:"feature count" >> shape_list.txt
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a built in `find` command you could use.  Do `help find` to see the options.

`for %f in (*.shp) do ogrinfo -al -so %f | find /I "feature count"`

If you need to reduce it down to just the count without the label you might have to find a different utility.

Comment: Thanks @mikewatt! The label is helpful. To add an additional tag like layer name, is the find command still useful?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of any way to "or" the find string.  Sounds like you might be better off writing some Python, Batch, or Powershell to get the job done

Comment: Thank you! Given **user2856**'s response using *findstr* with two string searches, I am able to pipe these two metadata tags into a text file: `FOR /R "dir" %f in (*.shp) do ogrinfo -al -so %f | findstr /I /c:"layer name" /c:"feature count" >> layer_feature_count.txt` I have one more issue to resolve: each of fifty folders contains identically named shapefiles so I need to append the subdirectory name to layer name and feature count. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you **user2856**! That did the trick.